# Static Azure FW for 3rd Parties to Whitelist

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-resource-manager

I’m trying to find a way to assign a static ip to out azure firewall. This IP will need to be shared with 3rd party vendors, I’m thinking of using a NAT gateway, but that doesn’t support inbound traffic.

Anyone know how I would assign a static ip to azure firewall so vendors can white list it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an Azure Firewall instance, you need to assign a public IP to this. So long as the public IP you create is configured to be static, then it will be a static IP. This can be used for inbound, and outbound traffic (so long as traffic is routed out the firewall).